# Copy 3D array to a vector using std::copy is possible.?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use std:copy to copy the 3D array to vector.

```
int myint[3][3][3] = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } },
                       { { 11,12, 13 }, { 14, 15, 16 }, {17, 18, 19 } },
                       { { 21, 22, 23 }, { 24, 25, 26 }, { 27, 28, 29 } } };

int favint[3][3][3];
```

I can copy the myint to favint as below

```
std::copy(&myint[0][0][0],
          &myint[0][0][0] + (sizeof(myint) / sizeof(*myint)) * (sizeof(*myint) / sizeof(**myint))*(sizeof(**myint) / sizeof(***myint)),
          &favint[0][0][0]);
```

I can copy the `myint` to `myvector` as below:

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > myvector;         
    for (int k = 0; k<sizeof(myint) / sizeof(*myint); k++)
    {
        myvector.push_back(vector<vector<int> >()); 
        for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(*myint) / sizeof(**myint); i++)
        {
            myvector[k].push_back(vector<int>()); 
            for (int j = 0; j<sizeof(**myint) / sizeof(***myint); j++)
            {                   
                myvector[k][i].push_back(myint[k][i][j]); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Copy 3D array to a 3D array is simple using std:: copy. How can I use the std::copy to copy the myint to myvector? Is there any other simple way?

Comment: You can do that with an array because the memory (all 27 `int`s) is contiguous; that won't be the case for the arrays within the `vectors`

Comment: Yes. It is possible to copy an array (regardless of dimensions) to a vector (or vectors).

Comment: I'm not sure than your way to copy array is pedantically correct, as `&myint[0][0][0] + 27` is out of inner array `int (&)[3]` of `myint[0][0][0]`.

Comment: @eerorika - Interesting, Could you share the example to copy an n-array to a n-vector? Is it possible through std::cop.?

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
std::vector<int> to_vector(const int (&a)[3])
{
    return {std::begin(a), std::end(a)};
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> to_vector(const int (&a)[3][3])
{
    return {to_vector(a[0]), to_vector(a[1]), to_vector(a[2])};
}

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> to_vector(const int (&a)[3][3][3])
{
    return {to_vector(a[0]), to_vector(a[1]), to_vector(a[2])};
}
```

For generic (but compile time) values, `template` might help:

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::vector<int> to_vector(const int (&a)[N])
{
    return {std::begin(a), std::end(a)};
}

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
auto to_vector(const int (&a)[N1][N2])
-> std::vector<std::vector<int>>
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
    res.reserve(N1);
    for (const auto& inner_a : a) {
        res.push_back(to_vector(inner_a));
    }
    return res;
}

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t N3>
auto to_vector(const int (&a)[N1][N2][N3])
-> std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> res;
    res.reserve(N1);
    for (const auto& inner_a : a) {
        res.push_back(to_vector(inner_a));
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bedd9cbc3ee1dc7)

Comment: Thanks.! This work for constant size[3] [3] [3]. Now I am trying to copy n dimension array to vector. Could you share some hints / example?

Comment: @mibkycan: added.

Comment: Thank you,Learning new here!
I tried the your code. Got Error->expected a trailing return type on returntype of 2D and 3D Vector. What could be the return value ?

Comment: Ok, you are in C++11 and not C++14, so replace return type by `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`.

Comment: Its not working.Replaced with return std::vector<std::vector<int>>; and return std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;

Comment: @mibkycan: Demo added.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `std::back_inserter`

```
std::copy(&myint[0][0][0],
          &myint[0][0][0] + sizeof myint / sizeof(int),
          std::back_inserter(myvector));
```

Comment: OP _should_ be using a 1D vector for this, but they're not, so this is wrong.